# magento can not load my custom model

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Hi I have a issue which I don't understand, please someone could help me.
I'm on the 1.8.1
I have a Module in app->code->local->Mycompany

- Mycampany

  - TestModel

    - etc

      - config.xml
    - Model

      - FirstModel.php

code in config.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_TestModel>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_TestModel>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <TestModel>
                <class>Mycompany_TestModel_Model</class>
            </TestModel>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

code in FirstModel.php

```
class Mycompany_TestModel_Model_FirstModel extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

    public function output()
    {
        echo "get";
    }
}
```

When I use

```
Mage::getModel('TestModel/FirstModel')
```

magento can not load the class.

I tested and it is working on my local machine.

Please help.

Plus. I also tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_TestModel>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_TestModel>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <testmodel> /* instead of <TestModel> */
                <class>Mycompany_TestModel_Model</class>
            </testmodel>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

I still can not get anything in

```
Mage::getModel('testmodel/FirstModel')
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: I did add a config file in the modules folder.

Comment: @Manashvibirla What do you mean by table? This is the whloe Module. just one test model.

Comment: check this out http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/04/creating-a-magento-custom-model

Answer (score 0):

As you use magento fatory method **[Mage::getModel('testmodel/FirstModel') ]**

that means you need to use it procedure to define an model.

As per as magento, when autoloader  execute testmodel/FirstModel  run like:

```
testmodel=Mycompany_TestModel_Model
```

and 
FirsModel is wrong ,File and name should be Firstmodel  as after model model folder( `Mycompany/TestModel/Model`) **all folders  and files name** should **first  letter with uppercase case** and `after that all  should be lower` a

That means file should be

- `Firstmodel.php` instead of `FirstModel`
- and  `testmodel/FirstModel` should be `testmodel/firstmodel`
- `NO underscore` should be use in `folders and file name`

Comment: You can use FirstModel as name. I just find the problem. the complier tool is enable, and I need to rebuild it.